# Skipping Blank Cells In A VBA For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Hi all this is my first time asking a question on here and it is probably pretty basic to most but this is my first time coding macros. I am working on an excel spread sheet long list of data values and need to delete all of the rows under a certain dollar amount, this part I have working perfectly. But i have blank cells that are on the same line as headers separating groupings that keep getting deleted I need to keep these. Is there a way to skip blank cells in the for loop.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long 

    For n = 1000 To 1 Step -1 

        If Cells(n, 9).Value < 1.01 Then Cells(n, 9).EntireRow.Delete 

    Next n 

End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
    For n = 1000 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(n, 9).Value < 1.01 Then Cells(n, 9).EntireRow.Delete
    Next n
End Sub

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45511392/edit) button to please add code to the body of the question. Also ensure it's properly indented/formatted in the question :)

Comment: Wrap your `If` statement in another `If` statement to test for empty cells, using e.g., the `IsEmpty` function, or comparing value against `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a condition in your if statement to ensure the cell is not blank. Like this:

```
If Len(Cells(n,9)) and Cells(n, 9).Value < 1.01 Then Cells(n, 9).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long

    For n = 1000 To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(n, 9).Value < 1.01 And Cells(n, 9).Value <> "" Then Cells(n, 9).EntireRow.Delete

    Next n

End Sub
```